# Inheritance, hiding and overriding

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, overriding, virtual

A little question about inheritance, hiding and overriding.

I have the following classes:

```
public class A
{
    public BasicProject project { get; set; }
    public int a {get; set;}
}

public class B : A 
{
    public AdvancedProject project { get; set; }
    public int b {get; set;} 
}

public class C : A
{
    public new AdvancedProject project { get; set; }
    public int c {get; set;}
}

public class BasicProject
{
    public int p1 {get; set;}
    public int p2 {get; set;}
}

public class AdvancedProject : BasicProject
{
    public int p3 {get; set;}
    public int p4 {get; set;}
}
```

Also I have some function

```
A show(A x)
{
    x.project.p1;
    x.project.p2;
    x.project.p3;
    x.project.p4;
}
```

The problem is that when I pass to function an object of type `B` (or `C`), the `x.project` refers to type `BasicProject` and NOT to `AdvancedProject`.

Comment: That's because the method only knows `A`.  If you want to access `B` properties you should either cast to `B` inside or use generics.

Comment: That's because `project` isn't virtual in `A`, and if it were you'd have to `override` it in `B` and even then it still has to have the same type.

Comment: @juharr adding virtual/override causes compilation error "type must be 'BasicProject' to match overridden" member 'A.project'

Comment: @ZoharPeled could you change my pseudo code please?

Comment: @Ilan Yes, I said the types have to be the same for you to be able to override them.  Otherwise you can only hide the property and you have to refer to it by casting to `B` like Zohar said.  I'm not sure if this is just a learning exercise or if this is a watered down version of something you're trying, but if it's the later then you might want to describe what you are attempting to use this for because this seems like a design issue.

Comment: class B should give you the 'hides ...' warning that goes to the core of this problem. class C avoids the warning but solves nothing with the `new` modifier.

Comment: @HenkHolterman yes, that's the problem.

Comment: The underlying problem is an invalid design that violates the Substitution rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach to handle it is this:

```
A show(A x)
{
    x.project.p1;
    x.project.p2;
    var y = x as B;
    if(y != null)
        y.project.p3;
        y.project.p4;
    }
    var z = x as C;
    if(z != null)
        z.project.p3;
        z.project.p4;
    }
}
```

However, this is an abuse of inheritance, and I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you're describing is by design, and you shouldn't try to work against it.

If you pass an argument of type `A` to a method, all that method knows is that it is of type `A`. The actual reference could be an instance of a class that inherits from `A`, but the method doesn't know that.

You almost always want to avoid casting something to see what the underlying type is. That defeats the purpose of inheritance and strong typing. We could just make all of our method arguments `object` and then try casting them to see what type they are. If you find yourself having to do that, it's a sign that something has gone wrong and it's good to backtrack and fix that before continuing.

It's not clear what `Show` is, but perhaps that should be a method of `BasicProject` which `AdvancedProject` can override. Or maybe those two classes have a method that produces some output (like a collection of values) and `Show` calls that method and does something with those values.

That way `Show` doesn't have to know whether it's talking to a `BasicProject` or `AdvancedProject`. It just calls a method of the class, and the result is different depending on which type it's talking to. That's polymorphism. You interact with the type you know about (`BasicProject`) without knowing whether you're actually dealing with an inherited class. You only want to "know" the type that's passed to the method.

For example:

```
public class BasicProject
{
    public int p1 { get; set; }
    public int p2 { get; set; }
    public virtual IEnumerable<int> GetValues()
    {
        return new [] {p1, p2};
    }
}

public class AdvancedProject : BasicProject
{
    public int p3 { get; set; }
    public int p4 { get; set; }

    public override IEnumerable<int> GetValues()
    {
        var values = new List<int>(base.GetValues());
        values.Add(p3);
        values.Add(p4);
        return values;
    }
}

public class AdvancedProject : BasicProject
{
    public int p3 {get; set;}
    public int p4 {get; set;}
}
```

Now your method `Show` just calls the `GetValues()` function. If the project is a `BasicProject` it gets one set of values, and if it's an `AdvancedProject` it gets another set of values. But it never needs to know which type that property is.
And nothing has to inherit from `A`.

This is part of the [Liskov Substitution Principle](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/dhananjay_kumar/archive/2015/06/30/simplifying-the-liskov-substitution-principle-of-solid-in-c.aspx). It basically says that if you have a method that calls for an argument of type `A`, then you can substitute an instance of any object that inherits from `A`. You don't have to know or care what the actual type is. As far as you're concerned it's `A` and that's all you need to know.